# Python operators workflow =+ and +=

Tags: python

what is the exact difference between these operators "+=" and "=+" in python?

for same input `[0,3,6]`

Program 1:

```
def total(numbers):
    result = 0
    for i in range(0, len(numbers)):
        result =+ numbers[i]
    return result

# output: 6
```

Program 2:

```
def total(numbers):
    result = 0
    for i in range(0, len(numbers)):
        result += numbers[i]

    return result

# output: 9
```

Comment: There is no operator `=+` in python. You have separate tokens for assignment `=` and unary plus, `+`.

Comment: `=+` is not an operator. It is assignment `=`, and the `+` is *not part of that*.

Comment: And all that said, you want `sum(numbers)`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `=+` syntax in Python; you have an [assignment statement `<target> = <expression>`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), and a [unary `+` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations); the latter applies jut to the `numbers[i]` expression:

```
result = (+numbers[i])
```

*Unary plus* just returns the number unchanged, it is there as the opposite of unary minus.

As a result, you *rebind* result first to `0`, then to `3` and finally to `6`. No summing takes place, so in the end you just return the last number from the list.

The `<target> += <expression>` syntax is called an [augmented assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements), and for immutable objects such an integers comes down to doing the same as `<target> = <target> + <expression>`.

Answer (score 1):

`foo += expr` usually means `foo = foo + expr`.

`foo =+ expr` is not something you should be writing, as it usually means `foo = + (expr)`.

Note that these behaviors can be overridden depending on what `foo` actually is, if `foo` happens to implement [certain magic methods](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html).

Answer (score 0):

In your first program, you assign the positive of `numbers[i]` to `result`, so `result` is in the end the value of the last number in the list.

The second program adds up all numbers with the `+=`-operator, which is the same as `result = result + numbers[i]`